# Scala Patch function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
object TestScala {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val mainList = List(3, 2, 1)
mainList.patch(1, Seq(5), 0)
println("mainList-->"+mainList)
 }
}
```

The output is `mainList-->List(3, 2, 1)` not expected one

I am expecting `3,5,2,1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala List is immutable.
Assign it to variable and it will produce desired output.

```
object TestScala {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
var mainList = List(3, 2, 1)
mainList  = mainList.patch(1, Seq(5), 0)
println("mainList-->"+mainList)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional languages like Scala prefer immutable data structures.

The answer provided by undefined_variable is correct but you should prefer val over var:

```
object TestScala {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val mainList = List(3, 2, 1)
   val newList  = mainList.patch(1, Seq(5), 0)
   println("newList-->"+newList)
  }
}
```